# floating numbers of value attributes in decision tree nodes (scikit-learn, randomforest)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, treeview, decision-tree, treenode

I tried to plot one single tree from a fitted random forest generated by scikit-learn. In the tree plot, each node includes some elements inclue a value list. I think usually the value list means the sample numbers of each class in that node. But the plot I got, values are floating numbers. I am so confused, how is that possible to have 100.447 samples.

The code I used to plot the tree is:

```
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree_test6.dot', feature_names = df_feature.columns,
                class_names = unique_labels(sample['Activity']), rounded = True, proportion = False, precision = 2, filled = True)
```

I changed one paramenter `precision = 2` into `precision = 0` the number after floating point became zero same as gini and threshold, that dose not solve the problem. I really want to know how to explain this floating number of value attribults.

The link is a figure of two nodes I got in the tree.

[a zoom two nodes of the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyED2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this for myself. Go back to your classifier and see if you're effectively getting it to sample certain classes multiple times. For me I was getting this "issue" because I had used class_weight='balanced' and then getting floats where I was expecting ints.

It was explained a long time ago here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2703